# How to read polyline cords from a *.tmx file?

Tags: java, libgdx, tmx, tiled

I am using TmxMapLoader and I can't seem to find a way to read polyline data from a *.tmx.

```
TmxMapLoader mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
TiledMap map = mapLoader.load("map1.tmx");      
MapLayers layers = map.getLayers();     
Iterator<MapLayer> layersIter = layers.iterator();      
while(layersIter.hasNext()) {
    MapLayer layer = layersIter.next();
    if(layer.getName().equals("path")) {
        MapObjects os = layer.getObjects();
        Iterator<MapObject> osIter = os.iterator();
        while(osIter.hasNext()) {
            MapObject o = osIter.next();
            MapProperties p = o.getProperties();
            // p.get("x") p.get("y") - <object x="" y""> works just fine
            // but how can I get all polyline data from <polyline>?
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant part of *.tmx file:

```
<objectgroup color="#9da0a4" name="path">
    <object x="9.09091" y="1509.09">
        <polyline points="0,0 1,1"/>
    </object>
</objectgroup>
```

I checked the code for TmxMapLoader and it seems that it has this functionality implemented, yet I can't find a way to get it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Polyline polyline = ((PolylineMapObject)o).getPolyline();?

Comment: Can I kiss you? ;-) Thanks! Not the greatest design though.

Comment: Hehehehe, oh no!!!, you're welcome :)

Comment: @vzamanillo Maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: @Thorbjørn, you got it, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Polyline as follows, where `o` is a `MapObject`:

```
Polyline polyline = ((PolylineMapObject)o).getPolyline();
```

Keep in mind that you may have check the instance before to prevent a ClassCastException

```
if(o instanceof PolylineMapObject) {
    Polyline polyline = ((PolylineMapObject)object).getPolyline();
    .....
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Additional info about Tile Maps at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps